# Add Line numbering on a Docx in PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, phpoffice

I work on docx uploaded by users and I want to add line numbering (like this: http://prntscr.com/n5rc1s) on the docx before exporting it in PDF.

I tried to add this with PhpOffice but I did not succeed.

My code can convert in PDF but without line numbering.

Thanks for your help :)

My code:

```php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');


define('PHPWORD_BASE_DIR', realpath(__DIR__));
$domPdfPath = realpath(PHPWORD_BASE_DIR . '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

//Open template and save it as docx
$document = $phpWord->loadTemplate('test.docx');
$document->saveAs('temp.docx');

//Load temp file
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('temp.docx');
$sections = $phpWord->getSections();
foreach ($sections as $section) {
    $section->getStyle()->setLineNumbering(array());

}
//Save it
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
$xmlWriter->save('result.pdf');
```

Comment: I find programs like BBEdit add line numbers, another that comes to mind is Programmers File Editor...

Comment: I can't open your screenshot. Please add it to your question, so we do not depend on external services.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you have to pass values to

```
$section->getStyle()->setLineNumbering(array());
```

instead of an empty array. In the [source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Style/Section.php#L164)

```
/**
 * Line numbering
 *
 * @var \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\LineNumbering
 * @see  http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_lnNumType-1.html
 */
private $lineNumbering;
```

there's a reference to [the schema](http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-w_lnNumType-1.html), so you actually have to pass values for `countBy`, etc. You probably want at least some spacing between the text and the line numbers, so you can do something like

```
$section->getStyle()->setLineNumbering(['countBy' => 1, 'restart' => 'continuous', 'distance' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(.2)]);
```